# listview link work only for the first items

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have strange problem, using data-role="listview" display JSON list.
only the first items that displayed at the Android screen link work, the other items that scroll down return to the first items.
i'm using jquerymbile 1.3.1
I tried:

```
overflow: scroll;
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
```

and

```
<script>
  $(document).bind("mobileinit", function(){
  $.mobile.touchOverflowEnabled = true;
  });
</script>
```

but still the same results
any idea why??
my list view:

```
<div data-role="page" id="getAll_JSON">
<div data-role="header" >
    <h1>info</h1>
</div>
<div data-role="content" >
  <ul id="sitesList" data-role="listview" data-filter="true" data-split-icon="gear" >
  </ul>
</div>
<div data-role="footer">
</div>
```

my jquery ajax:

```
    $.ajax({
    url: mysite+"func=getM",
    data: 'lat='+lat+"&long="+long,
    dataType: "json",
    cache: false, 
    error: function () {
        $('#coupons').append('error');
        } ,
onFailure: function () {
        $('#coupons').append('failure');
        } ,
statusCode: {
        404: function() {
        alert("no info");
            }   
        } ,
success: function (result) {
    $.each(result.sites,function(index,dat){
    $("#sitesList").append(
    '<li onClick="getSite(' + dat.coupon_id + ')">'+
    '<a href="#detailsPage">' +
    '<img src="images/'+dat.coupon_img+'" style="float:left" width=80/>' +
    '<p style="white-space:normal; margin-right:2em;">name :     <strong>'+dat.coupon_name+'</strong></p>'+
    '<p style="white-space:normal; margin-right:2em;">info : '+dat.street+'</p>'+
    '<p style="white-space:normal; margin-right:2em;">add: '+dat.coupon_tmp+'</p>'+
    '</a></li>'
    );
});

$('#sitesList').listview('refresh');
}
})
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove the `onClick` attribute from the `li`. Bind it to the `a` tag inside it.
2. Even better, use [delegation](http://www.sitepoint.com/event-delegation-with-jquery/)

   ```
   $("#sitesList").on("click", "a", function(e) {
   });
   ```
3. You could store that coupon id which ur passing to `getSite()` in a `data-` attribute when you're appending data into `li`:

   ```
   '<li>'+
   '<a href="#detailsPage" data-coupid="'+ dat.id +'">' +
   '<img src="images/'+dat.coupon_img+'" style="float:left" width=80/>' +
   '<p style="white-space:normal; margin-right:2em;">name :       <strong>'+dat.coupon_name+'</strong></p>'+
   '<p style="white-space:normal; margin-right:2em;">info : '+dat.street+'</p>'+
   '<p style="white-space:normal; margin-right:2em;">add: '+dat.coupon_tmp+'</p>'+
   '</a></li>'
   ```
4. use `preventdefault` when youre you're tapping on an `a` tag:

   ```
   $("#sitesList").on("click", "a", function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      getSite($(this).attr("data-coupid"))
   });
   ```
5. What's with the `href` in the `a`? arent you contradicting yourself? Your tapping on an `li` which will send the click to `a` which in turn will re-direct to `detailsPage`

Comment: I changed the Ajax success as follow but the link doesn't work at all

Comment: success: function(result) {
$.each(result.sites,function(index,dat){
$("#sitesList").on("click", "a", function(e) {e.preventDefault();
getSite($(this).attr("data-coupid"))});
$("#sitesList").append(
  '<li>'+'<a href="#detailsPage" data-coupid="'+ dat.id +'">' +
'<img src="images/'+dat.coupon_img+'" style="float:left" width=80/>' +
'<p style=" margin-right:2em;">name :      '+dat.coupon_name+'</p>'+
'<p style="white-space:normal; margin-right:2em;">info : '+dat.street+'</p>'+
'<p style="white-space:normal; margin-right:2em;">add: '+dat.coupon_tmp+'</p>'+
'</a></li>'
);
});

Comment: if I remove the: e.preventDefault(); the success results multiply by 5

Comment: I implement what you suggested but still the same resuls. List displayed correct but only the first items link are working. I changed my App and add long list with clickable link and buttons and noticed that only the first screen that displayed link are working the other that scrolled down not respond to he click,

Comment: u might have to setup a fiddle for this. just take the results from the ajax call and store it in a variable, assume that variable as the success of ur ajaxcall..

Comment: @user1377921 - just to be clear; **the other items that scroll down return to the first items** - u mean the page scrolls up to the first item when u click on something? is `getSite` an ajax call?

Comment: the first lists that displayed click working fine. when I scroll the list down and click at list bellow the items I clicked turn to the items on the top list

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it causes the problem or not, try to change `width=80` in your append list to `width="80"` ,like that,

```
$("#sitesList").append( 
'<li>'+
'<a href="#detailsPage" data-coupid="'+ dat.id +'">' + 
'<img src="images/'+dat.coupon_img+'" style="float:left" width="80" />' + 
'<p style=" margin-right:2em;">name : '+dat.coupon_name+'</p>'+ 
'<p style="white-space:normal; margin-right:2em;">info : '+dat.street+'</p>'+ 
'<p style="white-space:normal; margin-right:2em;">add: '+dat.coupon_tmp+'</p>'+ 
'</a></li>' );
```

Comment: I changed but doesn't help much. the ajax list displayed correct but when scroll down and click at the one of the images it doesn't clicked only the first screen images can be clicked

Comment: can you post your generated html, pls?